# anti-sql injection function

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-injection

I am using this function to prevent sql injections :

```
function filter($input)
{
  if(strpos(str_replace("''","","$input"),"'") != false)
  {
    return str_replace("'", "''", $input);
  }
  return $input;
}
```

**is it safe to use it? can someone somehow bypass it? if is is possible to bypass it please give me a hint on how to secure this function or an example on how you see bypass for it**

UPDATE : it is used on SQL Server

Comment: Duplicate of many questions asked out of assumption that a quote is the only character belongs to injection.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: @Gumbo yes it is for SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Please don't invent your own security solutions if you're not an expert on the problem domain.
Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php to learn more about SQL injection.

Also use proper prevention with http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

You don't need to invent your own if the tools are already there.

Comment: That's pretty nice words. Until they meet a real life.

Answer (score 0):

> is it safe to use it?

#### NO

> can someone somehow bypass it?

#### YES

1. It shouldn't be **input** filter by any means. But data formatter for the SQL query.
2. At the very least it have to be

   ```
   function SQLstrFormat($str)
   {
       return "'".str_replace("'", "''", $str)."'";
   }
   ```

this way it would be safe, when applicable.

Comment: Thanks, but can you also give an example on how to see bypass for this?, the \\'' won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
    function mysql_pre($value) {

            $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
            $new_enough_php =      function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string(unescaped_string)"); //i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0

            if($new_enough_php) { //PHP v4.3.0 or higher
                //undo any magic quote effect so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work

                if($magic_quotes_active) {$value = stripslashes($value);}

                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

            } else { //before PHP v4.3.0

                if(!$magic_quotes_active) {
                    $value = addslashes($value);
                }
            }
            return $value;
        }
```